# How to save setText?

Tags: android, save, settext

```
final Button haa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.haactiv);
    haa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dhas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dha);
            haout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.haoutput);
            haout.setText(dhas.getText());
        }
    });
```

I don't know how to save the output `haout` from the getText `dhas` for the next time I start the app.

Thanks for help!

Comment: What have you tried? There are countless examples of persisting data in Android

Comment: There's a button 'haactiv'. With this button the edit text 'dhas' is shown the output 'haout'. So the text written by the user is shown in 'haout'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save it in the shared preferences. Example:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

To read from the shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```

Some more information about shared preferences [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Comment: Thanks! I try it tomorrow. :)

Comment: can you answer how to do it with a .txt file? Than you get the checkmark for the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you need save data permanente.
Try save in a .txt file.